# Js datepicker formats and value

Tags: jquery, html, date, datepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I have date-picker input. So, when I select, it opens me 2 calendars (from and to specific date). After giving inputs it shows `01/2003 - 04/2005`, because format is set to `MM/YYYY`.

I need a way that format to be `DD/MM/YYYY`, and after selecting it should display me dates like `05/2010 - 06/2012`, but input value that goes to `back-end` to be like `30/10/2010 - 25/06/2012` (including days).

There is a way to achieve it?

#### HTML:

```
<input class="time_select" type="date" name="cv_study[dataTime][]" format="d/m/Y">
```

#### JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.time_select').daterangepicker({
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/YYYY'
        },
        startDate: '01/2010',
        endDate: '10/2012'
    });
});
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMKz0.png)

Check the image, I want input where is `dd/mm/yyyy` to be the final value of `05/2010 - 10/2015`, but the real value of input to be `01/05/2010 - 07/10/2015`

So, When I click at this input, appears 2 calendars.

First with value `01/2010`, second with `10/2012`.
I want to display value in that format, but the real value of the input to include `DAY` as well (`d/m/Y`).

Comment: Share what you have done so far

Comment: @Mr.x check again please

Comment: So why you simply don't change `format: 'MM/YYYY'` => to => `format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'`

Comment: @Mr.x in that case it displays me 15/01/2010 - 20/01/2010 in the input, but this value is to long and unnecessary for me. I need to show just month and year, but in backend to have a full string, and then to convert it to DataTime object

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="from" dateformat="d/M/Y" min="01/01/2010" type="date"/>
```

I am sure it will work.

> Updated for setting min date

Comment: I have 
$(document).ready(function () {
'.time_select' .daterangepicker(
        {
            locale: {
                format: 'MM/YYYY'
            },
            startDate: '01/2010',
            endDate: '10/2012'
        });
and at 
 <input class="time_select" type=" name="cv_study[dataTime][]" dateformat="d/m/Y">   and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you share the output/how it looks like ?

Comment: Check again,please

Comment: We probably have a misunderstanding. Can you please provide how should JS look and HTML, to be sure that ur solution works or not?